# Java Swing - Displaying lots of components in a single JPanel efficiently

Tags: java, performance, swing

I am working on a simple application that displays some properties in a Jpanel with a BoxLayout which has a ScrollPane.

Everything works nicely but I have 2000 entries I need to list, and my application works really slowly - it takes to much time to render everything.

What I'm doing is looping through an ArrayList of CustomisedJPanel objects and adding them to the main JPanel.

This is how it looks like.
[image: This is how it looks like]

Is there a way to make this efficient?
It takes way to much time to load.

Thanks!

Comment: I would assume, that if you would only instantiate the customised JPanels, which are currently shown and erase the ones which are not visible

Comment: *"I have 2000 entries"* Are they all displaying the same type of object (e.g. a 'patient record' or 'order details')? Maybe it would be more optimal to use a `JTable` or use the custom panel as a cell renderer for a `JList`. It would **certainly** be more efficient.

Comment: They are the same object type.

Comment: For better help post [mcve]

Comment: Thanks! I actually found a something on Google and solved the problem. I paged the JPanel, so I only loads the first 5 properties(houses)  and then you go to page 2 to load the next 5 and so on. Thanks for the help tho :)